# Having an issue with my setInterval method whenever I return to the window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using a setInterval method to create a banner slideshow for a current website project.

The banner seems to work fine. The jquery transition seems smooth enough, but what I am finding is that when I go to another window tab and then return to the website window after a few minutes, the slideshow kind of breaks its flow, and starts fadingout when it is not supposed to, images begin loading before the fadeout is complete etc.

Is this a browser issue? Or is is it to do with the fact I am using the delay method? Or something else I can not spot?

My code is below. Many thanks for taking the time to respond.

HTML:

```
<section id="banner">

<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">

<img src="banner1.jpeg" class="img-responsive center-block banner-img">

</div>
</div>

</section>
```

JAVASCRIPT / JQUERY:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var bannerImages = [
"banner1.jpeg",
"banner2.jpg",
"banner3.png"
];

var currentImage = 0;

$(".banner-img").fadeIn(500).delay(5000).fadeOut();

// CHANGE THE BANNER IMAGE EVERY FEW SECONDS
setInterval(function(){
if (currentImage > bannerImages.length-1){
currentImage = 0;
}

$(".banner-img").fadeIn().attr("src",bannerImages[currentImage]).delay(5000).fadeOut();
currentImage++;
}, 6000)

})
```

Comment: it may be caused relatively new feature when browsers throttle setInterval/setTimeout for inactive tab: https://content.pivotal.io/blog/chrome-and-firefox-throttle-settimeout-setinterval-in-inactive-tabs

Comment: Is there always an image in the banner?

Comment: @ShadowCommander I am not entirely sure if I can answer that with 100% certainty as I am new to programming and web development. I am still trying to learn what exactly goes on behind the scenes. I am only changing the src attribute of the image. So weather that means the image is always there, is beyond my knowledge at this stage. Apologies.

Answer (score 0):

<s>This may or may not be your problem, but you should declare `var currentImage` as it's currently in the global scope and not being garbage collected, so that running in the background every 5 seconds could be causing you problems. EDIT: looks like you fixed that so nevermind :)</s>

Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/7Ljt5f1x/
(Use the setinteral to fade out the previous image, then fade in the new image on complete)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var bannerImages = [
"banner1.jpeg",
"banner2.jpeg",
"banner3.jpeg"
];

var currentImage = 0;
var $bannerimg = $(".banner-img");
$bannerimg.fadeIn(500);

// CHANGE THE BANNER IMAGE EVERY FEW SECONDS
setInterval(function(){

  if (currentImage > bannerImages.length-1){
  currentImage = 0;
  }

  $bannerimg.fadeOut("fast", function(){
    $bannerimg.fadeIn(500).attr("src",bannerImages[currentImage]);
    currentImage++;
  });

}, 6000);

});
```

Comment: You should put the rest of your solution into your answer and add the relevant code from the jsfiddle just in case the link breaks.

Answer (score 0):

Try fading out the image inside of the setInterval function then fading in the new image instead of setting a delay on the fade out.